# Creating rearrangeable tabs in Swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

How to create rearrangeable tabs in Swing? Like that found in Google Chrome browser or Opera Browser. In which user can drag the tabs and can arrange it. Is it possible to achieve the same in Swing or JavaFx 2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code example [drag and drop tabs in jtabbedpane](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/04/drag-and-drop-tabs-in-jtabbedpane.html) that looks like what you are looking for.